How can I calculate the RSI for Bitcoin in Excel?
How can I calculate the Relative Strength Index (RSI) for Bitcoin in Excel? What formulas or steps should I follow to accurately compute the RSI using historical price data, and how can I implement this in an Excel spreadsheet?

The logic is the same for whatever price series you have.

What have you tried?

I have historical pricing data. No formulas for Excel. Can you help me with this?

The formula for the Relative Strength Index is:
RSI = 100 – 100 / ( 1 + RS )
where:
RS = is the ratio of the exponentially smoothed n-period gains divided by the absolute value of the exponentially smoothed moving average of the n-period losses
More detailed explanation along with examples of calculating this can be found by googling.

Okay, thanks. I was expecting more, but no more :(
